# Bubble sort to char pointers

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort, char-pointer

i am trying to make a program that inserts to an 'char** arr' a char pointer and then sort the char pointers with strcmp but for some reason its just don't work, the code i added is the sorting part of the entire code.

```
do
    {
        flag = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((strcmp(arr[i], arr[i + 1])) < 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            else if ((strcmp(arr[i], arr[i + 1])) > 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                temp = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }

            else if ((strcmp(arr[i], arr[i + 1])) == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 1);
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need *three* string comparisons, just one, saving the result to a variable is enough, then compare the variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on whether you want ascending order or descending order, you should only swap `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]` in one of the `if` cases. (either `strcmp() < 0` or `strcmp() > 0` case)
2. `flag` should only be assigned as 1 when swapping actually happens. Otherwise the loop won't stop.

Comment: Thank you, i tried what you said and the program still crashes. what do you think i should do?

Comment: @OfekEzon Use a debugger to check where it crashed and which pointer has incorrect value.